# Why is VS Code + Anaconda so slow on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Usually, I perform my coding under Linux using VS Code + Anaconda but, sometimes, I have to use a Windows machine. It is easy to sync to github and keep going on Windows on the same VS Code + Anaconda.

I try to use the Visual Studio Intellicode and the default python extensions but on Windows the experience is painfully slow.

To run the code (yes, just the imports) below (the first run) takes 26.509 sec:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
```

I can see that `Microsoft.Python.LanguageServer` is eating up to 60% CPU from my i7 notebook and more than 1500 MB RAM (sometimes with intensive I/O activity on my disk).

Anyone facing the same issues?

By the way, I'm using Python 3.7.2 and all packages installed with the default conda channels.

Comment: If it's just on the first run, this might be because Python is compiling the modules, which your linux system already did in its first run

Comment: The subsequent runs are taking ~2 sec (and that is too much). A bigger code that runs in less than 1 sec on Linux is taking ~15 sec on Windows.

Comment: And it is the same hardware? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: It is the exact same hardware. Actually, it is a dual boot (that I have to use because some of the softwares I need are Windows specific... one of the perks in the chemistry field).

Comment: While Windows can be a bit of a pain to work with, I never heard of such a drastic decrease in performance. Could maybe be a driver problem or it's because VS is initialising the debugger by default every run, which takes a while. Try running without the debugger and see if the time changes maybe

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @user8408080. I'll give it a try and send you an update here.

Comment: Same experience for me. Running the same unittest on both Windows 10 and the OSX. Took less than a second to complete the test on OSX but 18 secs (!) to complete on Windows.